# SpringBoot & Micrometer : tagging Meter with authenticated user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, micrometer

I try to add a dynamic tag to the micrometer Metric object by this way but authenticated user are always null even if it's not the case in the rest of services.

```java
    @Bean
    public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
        return new MeterFilter() {
            @Override
            public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
                String uri = id.getTag("uri");
                if (uri != null && uri.contains("/api")) {
                    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                    if (authentication != null) {
                        id.withTags(Tags.of("user", authentication.getName()));
                    }
                }
                return id;
            }
        };
    }
```

`Authentication` object is always null due to `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` call at the end of the `FilterChain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be a good idea since the username (principal) is possibly high cardinality data, see this article for more details: https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/

Instead of doing this, you can attach the username to you spans and correlate metrics using Exemplars.